# AWS cognito sso user authentication with django rest framework, react js, and ALB

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, amazon-cognito, okta-api

I am using [Okta SSO](https://www.okta.com/uk/products/single-sign-on/) user authentication in `aws-cognito`. After authentication it redirects to the Amazon load balancer and the frontend URL is loaded in the browser. To get the user-data I need to get the code that is passed in:

https://example.com/oauth2/idpresponse?code=xxx

This URL, along with other URLs, can be seen in the network tab of my browser's developer console. Is there any way I can access the code that's passed with this URL?

I am using reactjs for frontend and django-rest-framework for backend.

Comment: Thanks @rmlockerd for the edit. Please let me know if you find and answer for this

Comment: created a work around for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a work around, redirect api from ABL contains the header, redirect that to a custom api of your choice